# Collections.sort that accept multiple parameters

Tags: java, collections

I am new to Java. I am learning about Java Collections and I have question about writing a program to sort by attributes. So I have a class Course with these variables:

```
public class Course{
    private String courseName;
    private String courseDescription;
}
```

And another class Student that contains class Course which is a linked list of Course variables:

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private LinkedList<Course> courses;
}

public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = new LinkedList<Course>();
}
```

I want to write a method *public void sortCourse() { }* in Student class that should accept parameters to specify whether the sorting should be ascending or descending and also based on which course attribute to sort the courses, and print the sorted list of course. How can I write this method?

Comment: Make it accept a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Fureeish said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021454/collections-sort-that-accept-multiple-parameters#comment107956896_61021454): Make it accept a `Comparator`.

Like this:

```
public void sortCourse(Comparator<Course> comparator) {
    this.courses.sort(comparator);
}
```

The caller would then write something like this:

```
// Sort ascending by name
student.sortCourse(Comparator.comparing(Course::getCourseName));

// Sort decending by name
student.sortCourse(Comparator.comparing(Course::getCourseName).reversed());

// Sort ascending by course level, then description
student.sortCourse(Comparator.comparing(Course::getCourseLevel)
                         .thenComparing(Course::getCourseDescription));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Comparable` interface to sort the courses. For that your `Course` class need to implements the `Comparable` interface.

```java
public class Course implements Comparable <Course>{
    private String courseName;
    private String courseDescription;

    public Course(String courseName, String courseDescription){
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }

    public int compareTo(Course c) {
        return this.courseName.compareTo(c.courseName); 
    }

}
```

Now you can call `Collections.sort(student.courses)` method to sort the course list.

```java
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private LinkedList<Course> courses;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = new LinkedList<Course>();
    }

    public void sortCourse(String sortOrder){

        if(sortOrder.equals("asc")){
            Collections.sort(this.courses);
        } else {
            Collections.sort(this.courses);
            Collections.reverse(this.courses);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question said *"method `public void sortCourse() { }` in `Student` class that should **accept parameters** to specify whether the sorting should be ascending or descending and also based on which course attribute to sort the courses"*. This answer entirely failed to answer the question.

Comment: @Andreas You have added the comment while i'm editing the code

Comment: Yes, because you should have completed the code before posting it. We cannot see if you're in the process of editing the answer, we can only comment on what we can see. --- I see you added option for *"ascending or descending"*, but you're still missing *"which course attribute to sort"*.